# Shortest Path Problem: Pickup All Deliveries within time constraint with least pickup drivers

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

I want to know what would be the best/state of art algorithm to solve below problem:

We have a list of 1000 deliveries (ID, [Lat,Long]).. which needs to be picked using least number of delivery guys, and the constraints of problem are,

- Each guy need to start from origin[0,0], and come back to origin[0,0] within 720 minutes
- Picking up a delivery will take time depending on distance
  e.g from (0,1) to (2,3) is sqrt((2-0)^2+(3-1)^2)) minutes
- 1000 delivery points are as follows
  [scatter_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbbAv.png)    [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7tQR.png)

So any suggestion about any direction to any recent research or state of art algorithm to solve such problems shall be highly appreciated! Thank you

I have managed to collect all(1000) deliveries in 223 shifts... But still baseline is 220, i must beat it....

Comment: Share what you have done namely `code` so far